# MySQL workbench creates forward script dropping of tables in wrong sequence, violating foreign key constraints

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

The subject line actually says it all.

I have a schema, now when I create a forward script it generates the tables and I added the option to do a DROP TABLE IF EXISTS in front of every create table SQL. The creation part is fine. But if you run the script twice you notice that the drop sequence is the wrong order.

I think the concept of aligning the drop sequence with the create sequence is just conceptually arguable. I think you might be able to create schemas where you won't be able to create the tables in the same sequence as you would drop them.

Anyhow, I can't find any option to change the order or do anything. Has anyone an idea how I can change the drop sequence manually ?

I am sorry to be not able to share any SQL, however I think the problem is really generic. And you want solve it by writing different SQL. So it should be possible to answer based on discussion, not on code.

That's Workbench version 6.3.6. So almost latest. (Currently 6.3.7)

Comment: It never ceases to amaze me why these tools screw up like this. Ditto for the way some programmers show their code order when creating them.

Comment: Isn't that handled by switching off FK checks? There is no ultimative right order to drop tables. For instance they can reference each other creating so reference cycles (which is the reason why dump tools create dummy tables for views first and later drop the dummies and create the real views).

Answer (score 0):

You must drop table in reverse order of creating them.

When creating:

```
Create table a...;
Create table b...;
Create table c...;
```

When dropping:

```
Drop table c;
Drop table b;
Drop table a;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but as one of the above comments suggests "There is no ultimate right order to drop tables." You can construct foreign keys in a way that your rule around order won't work anymore. You need to write some algorithm that calculates the right create and drop order separated by basically trying every possible combination and checking the foreign key. That is in fact what everybody does manually.